# How do I compare multiple rows in the same table and tag them with different values?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So my problem seems simple to solve but gets complex quickly.  I want to be able to compare the sequence numbers for each task ID and tag them differently based on whether they are consecutive or not.  I have a table like this:

| task_id | seq_num | phase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4444444 | 7 | Check |
| 4444444 | 8 | Check |
| 4444444 | 9 | Check |
| 4444444 | 10 | Check |
| 4444444 | 53 | Check |
| 4444444 | 54 | Check |
| 4444444 | 55 | Check |
| 4444444 | 91 | Check |
| 4444444 | 92 | Check |

And the output I need is:

| task_id | seq_num | phase | grouping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4444444 | 7 | Check | Check 1 |
| 4444444 | 8 | Check | Check 1 |
| 4444444 | 9 | Check | Check 1 |
| 4444444 | 10 | Check | Check 1 |
| 4444444 | 53 | Check | Check 2 |
| 4444444 | 54 | Check | Check 2 |
| 4444444 | 55 | Check | Check 2 |
| 4444444 | 91 | Check | Check 3 |
| 4444444 | 92 | Check | Check 3 |

I was messing around with lag() and load() but I'm having some trouble.  Can anyone please help guide me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract a sequential value from `seq_num`.  This is constant, when the values are incrementing by 1.

Then, use `dense_rank()` to assign a grouping:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by task_id order by seq_num - x) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by task_id order by seq_num) as x
      from t
     ) t;
```

An alternative method is to use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_seqnum = seqnum - 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by task_id order by seq_num) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             lag(seq_num) over (partition by task_id order by seq_num) as prev_seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon!  dense_rank worked perfectly for what I needed.  I will definitely be using it in the future!